# Syntax error keeping me from creating a new table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a SQL table into which I will later import data from a csv file. I'm getting an error when I try to create the table but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Here is my SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_name`. ( 
    `YID` INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    `AST` INT(4) NOT NULL , 
    `KID` INT(5) NOT NULL , 
    `PKD` INT(12) NULL , 
    `LAT` DOUBLE(8,6) NULL , 
    `LNG` DOUBLE(8,6) NULL , 
    `KOGnim` VARCHAR(50) ,
    `PST` INT ,
    `ESI` INT ,
    `PLK` VARCHAR(50),
    `PRE` INT,
    `LKM` INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`YID`)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

And here is the error message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(
    `YID` INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `AST` INT(4) NOT NULL ,
' at line 1
```

I'm running mySQL v5.7

Comment: you have added "." (dot) after the table name.

Answer (score 1):

Found it! It was the period after `table_name`

Answer (score 0):

I think that this will do the trick

```
CREATE TABLE `table_name` ( 
    `YID` INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    `AST` INT(4) NOT NULL , 
    `KID` INT(5) NOT NULL , 
    `PKD` INT(12) NULL , 
    `LAT` DOUBLE(8,6) NULL , 
    `LNG` DOUBLE(8,6) NULL , 
    `KOGnim` VARCHAR(50) ,
    `PST` INT ,
    `ESI` INT ,
    `PLK` VARCHAR(50),
    `PRE` INT,
    `LKM` INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(`YID`)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```